# In Fable 3, can I have several wives in the same city?

Tags: fable-3

I’ve been playing for a while and I haven’t really tried because I don’t know if it’s possible. Is it possible to have more than one wife? I’m also wondering if anybody has tried to have multiple spouses in one city? Can some one please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing's stopping you from marrying multiple people, but you can only have one "proper" relationship. That is to say, Fable 3 does not recognize polyamorism.

The exceptions to this are:

- Other cities. You can have one "actual" relationship per city.
- Other players. NPCs do not recognize a marriage to another player.

The only restriction is you can only have one spouse per property you own in a city. That said, if you have more than one marriage in the same city, all spouses you have in that city will be quickly looking for a divorce.

Comment: Okay. I’ll definitely make sure to avoid that!